# UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, datasource

I know that the cellForRowAtIndexPath method isn't being called because I never see the `NSLog` messages inside of it. I have set the `dataSource` and `delegate` attributes of the `UITableView` and I also have declared `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` in the header file. What am I missing?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
matchesForUser = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
sortedFirstArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
sortedSecondArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

_tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 20) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
_tableView.dataSource = self;
_tableView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:_tableView];

countUsers = 0;
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
            tableData[countUsers] = [object valueForKey:@"username"];
            matchesForUser[countUsers] = [object valueForKey:@"matches"];
        }
    }else{
        NSLog([error description]);
    }

    NSLog(@"***tabledata***");
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[tableData count]]);
    NSLog(@"***matchesdata***");
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[matchesForUser count]]);
}];

dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:matchesForUser forKeys:tableData];
sortedFirstArray = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
sortedSecondArray = [dictionary objectsForKeys:sortedFirstArray notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];

backToMap = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 518, 160, 30)];
backToMap.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0f/255.0f green:156.0f/255.0f blue:41.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
[backToMap addTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backToMap setTitle:@"BACK TO MAP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:backToMap];
}

- (void)dismiss {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *username = [[sortedFirstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByAppendingString:@" "];
    NSString *matchAmount = [sortedSecondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"***username***");
    NSLog(username);
    NSLog(@"***matchamount***");
    NSLog(matchAmount);

    cell.textLabel.text = [username stringByAppendingString:matchAmount];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your tableData array? means it contains any object or not? because i check your code with static data and it works fine.

Comment: And yes reload your tableview after for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Here you do need to use **countUsers = 0**;If you need than you need to  increment the value inside for loop by 1.Otherwise it will overwrite the value at index 0 every time.

2) You are using background calling method to fetch data.So it will take time to fetch data and control will go further and execute following code.But At that time **matchesForUser array** is empty, and **dictionary** is also empty.So in cell it won't display anything and you will not see NSLOG from cell.

Instead of this

ini

```
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:matchesForUser forKeys:tableData];
sortedFirstArray = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
sortedSecondArray = [dictionary objectsForKeys:sortedFirstArray notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
```

3) Try with this,

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
                [tableData addObject:[object valueForKey:@"username"]];
                [matchesForUser addObject:[object valueForKey:@"matches"]];
            }
            dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:matchesForUser forKeys:tableData];
            sortedFirstArray = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
            sortedSecondArray = [dictionary objectsForKeys:sortedFirstArray notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
            [_tableView reloadData];

        }else{
            NSLog([error description]);
        }

        NSLog(@"***tabledata***");
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[tableData count]]);
        NSLog(@"***matchesdata***");
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[matchesForUser count]]);
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 5):

Try doing the following things

1.) Register your tableView like

```
[_tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SimpleTableItem"];
```

2.) Then Add `[_tableView reloadData];`   just below

```
for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
        tableData[countUsers] = [object valueForKey:@"username"];
        matchesForUser[countUsers] = [object valueForKey:@"matches"];
    }
```

Inside `if (!error)` part..

So your Updated Code must look like

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
if (!error) {
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
        tableData[countUsers] = [object valueForKey:@"username"];
        matchesForUser[countUsers] = [object valueForKey:@"matches"];
    }
    [_tableView reloadData];
}else{
    NSLog([error description]);
}

NSLog(@"***tabledata***");
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[tableData count]]);
NSLog(@"***matchesdata***");
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[matchesForUser count]]);
}];
```

Comment: got everything working now - why do i need to register my tableview?

Comment: Registering tableview will automatically generate view for that particular cell identifier. This will help in fast ui updation when you will be calling cellForRowAtIndex

Answer (score 1):

Did you reload the Tableview in ViewDidLoad? like

```
[_tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

Reload the table again after

```
dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:matchesForUser forKeys:tableData];
sortedFirstArray = [[dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
sortedSecondArray = [dictionary objectsForKeys:sortedFirstArray notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];

[_tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [tableData count];
}
```

The `count` is 0? you can type `NSLog("%@", @(tableData.count));` or just `return 1;` for test.
`UITableView` send the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` first, if the method return 0. it will not call the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

And as @PiyushSharma mentioned, you should `Register your tableView`.

Comment: `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`  add `[tableview reloadData]` if there is **No Error**.